# embed sound file without revealing source URL

Tags: php, jquery, html, flash, streaming

I have a number of sound files hosted by a third-party.

I would like to embed these on my site in some kind of player for streaming.

However, I need to hide the source URLs of these files from my users.

The point is to prevent users from discovering information about the third-party services we use, as some of this info is considered proprietary.

There is obviously no way to do this in straight html. Most methods that I have seen of embedding audio would leave URLs easily discoverable by just viewing the page source.

Is there a good way to keep this data hidden?

Comment: You might be use a custom-built Flash player that will retrieve the final URL from the server, which will at least hide it from the HTML source code. You have, however, no chance of hiding it from a person with a packet sniffer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend streaming the files from a streaming media server instead of a progressive downloaded file directly from the 3rd party.  Look into [red5 - opensource media server](http://www.red5.org/)